# SQL - Removing result of one table based on the tree structure of another

Tags: sql, inner-join, aggregate-functions, having-clause

To better define the question I'm asking, it'd probably be easier to introduce you to the data I'm working with.

Essentially I have two tables joined that kind of look like this:

Table 1

```
Product ID    AccountLinkID (FK)
PRODUCT00001  AC000001
PRODUCT00001  AC000002
PRODUCT00001  AC000003
PRODUCT00001  AC000004
```

Table 2

```
Link (FK)     AccountType
AC000001      1
AC000002      2
AC000003      3
AC000004      4
```

As part of some data i'm looking at, I want to make sure that if any ProductID is linked to an account type '4' that the product ID is removed from the search.

The problem Is that the foreign key isn't also a single number - as one product can be linked to multiple account types (for example, one produce could be linked to a sellers account, buyers account, customer account etc)

So in this instance - account type 4 is something like a 'dummy' account, therefore any productID's linked to it aren't ID's I want including in the search.

I can't think of how to use the account type as a means to remove the product id.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just one row per `productid`, you can join, aggregate, and filter out with a `having` clause

```
select t1.productid
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.link = t1.accountlinkid
group by t1.productid
having max(case when t2.accounttype = 4 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

If, on the other hand, you want entire rows from `t1`, then window functions are a better option:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t1.*, 
        max(case when t2.accounttype = 4 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by t1.productid) has_type4
    from table1 t1
    inner join table2 t2 on t2.link = t1.accountlinkid
) t
where has_type4 = 0
```